issue in eclipse and sts4 running an application: ClassNotFoundException: com.teamium.TeamiumApplication
I have cloned a repository from GitHub. Now I'm getting error in eclipse or sts 3:

Error: Could not find or load main class com.teamium.TeamiumApplication Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teamium.TeamiumApplication.

It's an enterprise application, my company gave me a repo, I cloned it in eclipse, and sts4, but getting the same error. jdk 20  is installed on my laptop.
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    
    
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent> its parent version.

I have updated the maven project multiple times. What is wrong here?

spring-boot 1.5.1.RELEASE  ? use JDK 1.8. (JDK 8)

First Spring Boot 1.X is very long end of life ... use more recent versions of Spring Boot...also you have to use JDK8 at max...
